# "Attach to process" in Visual Studio 2015 Update2/Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have just installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 on my Windows 10 machine (both x64 versions) and I am having hard time getting the debugger to work. When I try to attach to any process via Debug menu, I keep on getting:

[image]

I have tried reinstalling, repairing Visual studio few times always get the same error. Even running a basic hello world console application gives the same error.

When trying to run a web application using the IIS Web Express 8/10.

[image]

Even though I am absolutely sure that the message of corrupt installation is misleading, but I even have tried repairing visual studio from control panel and nothing seems to work. I dont even get any error logged anywhere which is keeping me stumped for last 1 day. This is what my VS installation looks like:
[image]

I am running the visual studio as administrator. I am pretty sure this is not a windows error as I tried installing VS2012 and debugging works in it.

Any ideas?